# In Ansible ,can we loop through list of files and match content in file using lineinfile module

Tags: ansible

I have to find all config.xml on a server and produce the list on a given server.

Once we registered the files list, i have to check the content in each file on the list using Ansible

I tried to derive the paths for all config.xml
register them and print the list
Added the registered variable into lineinfile path

```
##Derive Config.xml path
- name: Find the location of xml file
  shell: find {{ wlx_mount_point }} -maxdepth 1 -name {{xml_file}} | rev | cut -d '/' -f3- | rev
  register: wlx_domain_home
  ignore_errors: yes

- debug:
    msg: "{{ wlx_domain_home.stdout_lines|list }}"

- name: check domain home directory exists
  stat:
    path: "{{ wlx_domain_home |list }}"
  ignore_errors: true

- debug:
    msg: "{{ wlx_domain_home.stdout_lines|list }}"

    - name: "Ensure Logging Settings in config.xml"
      lineinfile:
        line: "{{ item.line }}"
        regexp: "{{ item.regexp }}"
        path: "{{ wlx_domain_home.stdout_lines|list }}/config/config.xml"
        state: present
        backrefs: yes
      register: config.xml.Logging
      with_fileglob: "{{ wlx_domain_home.stdout_lines|list }}/config/config.xml"
      with_items:
        - line: "<logger-severity>Info</logger-severity>"
          regexp: "^logger-severity.*"
```

Expected results are , it has to look for lines in each file and loop through the list. ` Its printing the list and not able to find the content

> "_ansible_ignore_errors": true, "msg": "Destination
>   [u'/appl/cmpas9/user_projects/pte-ipscasws',
>   u'/appl/bbb/user_projects/qa-ucxservices_bkp',
>   u'/appl/app/user_projects/weiss_apps12',
>   u'appl/view/user_projects/weiss_apps12_oldbkp',
>   u'appl/voc/user_projects/qa-voc']/config/config.xml does not exist !"
>   }

Comment: You should general add additional information to your question, rather than posting it as a comment. You are able to edit your question after you've posted it.

Comment: You can't have two `with_` loops on a task. Also note that `with_fileglob` looks at files on your *local system*, not the target on which Ansible is running.

Comment: can i use shell command instead to check the content using egrep into list of files? What is the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is how i fixed the issue. Now it gives output 
- name: find all weblogic domain paths
  shell: find /tech/appl -type f -name config.xml
  register: wlx_domain_config
- debug:
    var: wlx_domain_config.stdout_lines

- name: "Ensure allow-unencrypted-null-cipher Encryption Settings  in config.xml"
  shell: grep -i "" {{ item }}
  with_items: "{{ wlx_domain_config.stdout_lines }}"
  register: allowunencrypted
- debug:
  var: allowunencrypted.stdout_lines